# Using Log4j JMS appender to connect with ActiveMQ

Tags: log4j, mule, activemq-classic, esb

I am trying to add logging to our Mule application with ActiveMQ so all Messages are written to a SQL Server Database. THis is the content of my Log4j properties file in Mule:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console, jms

log4j.logger.org.apache.activemq=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %d [%t] %c: %m%n


# Mule classes
log4j.logger.org.mule=INFO
log4j.logger.com.mulesoft=INFO

# Your custom classes
log4j.logger.com.mycompany=DEBUG

# JMS Appender
log4j.appender.jms=org.apache.log4j.net.JMSAppender
log4j.appender.jms.InitialContextFactoryName=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
log4j.appender.jms.ProviderURL=tcp://sjc04-wduatesb1:9162
#tcp//localhost:61616
log4j.appender.jms.TopicBindingName=logTopic
log4j.appender.jms.TopicConnectionFactoryBindingName=ConnectionFactory
```

As you can see I am trying to use the JMS appender . I also have a JNDI config file to point to the topic to read off , the contents of that file stored in $MULE_HOME/conf/ is

topic.logTopic=logTopic

However I find even though messages are getting enqueued & dequeued on the topic , it is not being written to the database. Does anybody have any ideas or suggestions as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: There's no queuing in topics (unless you use a durable subscriber) so not sure what you're seeing being enqueued. Also: what database?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to create a subscriber to the topic that puts the message in a queue and then have a queue consumer put the message in the DB.